# Auto populating new field with date from another field for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a field that has a datepicker, but what I want that field, called New Date, to have populate with the date in the div id="olddate" plus one day.  The problem I'm seeing is that the date in the olddate div is a text string, so I need to convert that into a date object, put it in the New Date field and add a day.  I also prefer to keep it in jQuery, if possible.  I've seen plenty of answers to questions very similar to this, but nothing seems to work.  Thanks in advance!!  Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Carlos1815/U9Avn/

Here's what I got thus far:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script>    
$(function() {
        var olddate = $("#olddate").text(); 
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", olddate);
        });      
</script>
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="olddate">3/30/2013</div>
    <div>New Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I can get it so the date object populates the New Date field +1 day, I won't even really need the datepicker to begin with, but I'm still stumped as to why I can't get it to work the way I described.

Comment: I updated my answer using moment.js. have a look, it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worth to use <kbd>[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)</kbd> at this moment to solve this date time problems.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/U9Avn/7/)**

```
$(function () {        
    var day = moment($("#olddate").text(), "MM/DD/YYYY");
    day.add('days', 1)
    var newDate=day.toDate();    
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", newDate);
});
```

Comment: Most excellent, thank you!  I had to put in a -1 into the second Date parameter in order for the date to be closer to what I need:

Comment: var newDate = new Date(parseInt(olddate[2],10), parseInt(olddate[0],10)-1, parseInt(olddate[1],10)+1);

But this allowed me to get the datepicker to work correctly.  Thank you, again!

Comment: That did indeed clean things up.  Thanks again!  Works like a charm.